# initialize plugin in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have a carrousel which on display once a button is clicked. Problem is it doesnt get initialized straight away as the div is hidden so the carrousel is broken for the first few seconds. Is there away around this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 $("#category-slider").flexisel({
    visibleItems: 6,
    animationSpeed: 1000,
    autoPlay: true,
    autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
    pauseOnHover: true,
    enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
    responsiveBreakpoints: { 
        portrait: { 
            changePoint:480,
            visibleItems: 1
        }, 
        landscape: { 
            changePoint:640,
            visibleItems: 2
        },
        tablet: { 
            changePoint:768,
            visibleItems: 3
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check the plugin documentation actually?

Comment: wrap this plugin in a click event that will show the carrousel div

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you initialize your carousel in the same moment when you unhide your div? E.g. in a click-function wrapper. Something like:

```
$('#mybutton').one('click', function() {
    $('#mydiv').show();

    $("#category-slider").flexisel({
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but seems add extra elements into the carrousel if i open the hidden div again. i.e i end up having 3 next and previous buttons

Comment: Plugin is getting initialized every time the button is clicked therefore adding next and previous buttons

Comment: Hi Steve, try to use one() instead of on() for binding on the click event. With one the handler is unbound after its first invocation.